# Delaunay triangulation algorithm in shapely producing erratic result

Tags: python, shapely, computational-geometry

I would like to triangulate the following polygon:

[image]

The wkt for the geometry is given as follows:

```
POLYGON ((3 0, 2 0, 2 0.75, 2.5 0.75, 2.5 0.6, 2.25 0.6, 2.25 0.2, 3 0.2, 3 0))
```

I ran this code to generate the triangles

```
triangles = shapely.ops.triangulate(res_intersection.geometry.values[0])
triangles_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame()
triangles_gdf.geometry = triangles
```

When I take a look at the resulting polygon this is what I get:

[image]

However this is not what I want. The algorithm seems to generate some extra triangles which Are not contained in the original geometry. Why does this occur? Is there a workaround for this? Ultimately I would like to triangulate a large irregular polygon with holes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not producing an 'erratic' result. it takes the vertices as inputs as stated in the manual:

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.triangulate

Nothing stops you from clipping the result with the original shape, if that is what you want.

Comment: you can, but that comes with the additional overhead associated with `geopandas.overlay`

Comment: I don't think that is guaranteed to only produce triangles.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wFedfXU for p = Polygon(([
    (-10,0.5), (-10,1),(0.5,1), (10,1),
    (10,-1), (0,-1), (0,0), (1,0),
    (9,0), (9,0.5)
]))

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer

The best solution I could come up with is to first create voronoi regions using the boundary points (a small inside buffer was needed to ensure all boundary points are considered for the voronoi) as point input (also add interior points for polygons with holes). Then you can triangulate the voronoi regions and select the polygons which has their centroid inside the original polygon.

I have tested the code with examples of triangulations that people struggled with. (Note: Sometimes it looks like the plots does not show enough triangles but if you zoom in and out you will see them)

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import triangulate
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords

def to_triangles(polygon):

    poly_points = []

    gdf_poly_exterior = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [polygon.buffer(-0.0000001).exterior]}).explode().reset_index()
    for geom in gdf_poly_exterior.geometry:
        poly_points += np.array(geom.coords).tolist()

    try:
        polygon.interiors[0]
    except:
        poly_points = poly_points
    else:
        gdf_poly_interior = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [polygon.interiors]}).explode().reset_index()
        for geom in gdf_poly_interior.geometry:
          poly_points += np.array(geom.coords).tolist()

    poly_points = np.array([item for sublist in poly_points for item in sublist]).reshape(-1,2)

    poly_shapes, pts = voronoi_regions_from_coords(poly_points, polygon)
    gdf_poly_voronoi = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': poly_shapes}).explode().reset_index()
    gdf_poly_voronoi.plot()

    tri_geom = []
    for geom in gdf_poly_voronoi.geometry:
        inside_triangles = [tri for tri in triangulate(geom) if tri.centroid.within(polygon)]
        tri_geom += inside_triangles

    gdf_poly_triangles = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': tri_geom})

    gdf_poly_exterior.plot()
    if 'gdf_poly_interior' in locals():
        gdf_poly_interior.plot()
    gdf_poly_triangles.plot()

polygon_1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 3), (5, 3), (2, 4), (6, 4), (6, 0)])
polygon_2 = Polygon([(3.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.75), (2.5, 0.75), (2.5, 0.6), (2.25, 0.6), (2.25, 0.2), (3.0, 0.2), (3.0, 0.0)])
poly_3_wkt = 'POLYGON ((-74.05644319847762 4.664371152795165, -74.05701264773319 4.663503533579181, -74.05770573357918 4.662810447733186, -74.05896428283818 4.662056102337443, -74.05990224838993 4.661771573597983, -74.06224145161008 4.661772473597984, -74.06317941716183 4.662057002337444, -74.06443796642083 4.662811347733187, -74.06572065226682 4.664052233579182, -74.06921901369725 4.668360960588712, -74.07141674761461 4.670691972117472, -74.07635895116509 4.673818151938486, -74.07894493390593 4.675834266094067, -74.08192435226682 4.679424333579181, -74.08891615226682 4.688383433579182, -74.08958587724112 4.689463067989243, -74.09086467349047 4.690719228823506, -74.09790275116509 4.694460551938487, -74.10034036642082 4.696114147733187, -74.10386724657296 4.698958762835078, -74.10814346936803 4.700870863662334, -74.10930545161006 4.700957773597984, -74.11043741716183 4.701320402337444, -74.11139045116509 4.701828051938487, -74.11214813390593 4.702449866094067, -74.11445885226682 4.704984433579183, -74.11521319766256 4.706242982838176, -74.11590442640203 4.70845234838992, -74.11611382363337 4.710865185701647, -74.11554750632175 4.71273208368413, -74.11467343390593 4.713910633905932, -74.11305131716183 4.714994497662556, -74.11211335161008 4.715279026402015, -74.11073328554708 4.715355222566556, -74.11041129766257 4.716545717161825, -74.1094660522668 4.718057466420818, -74.10756213390592 4.720161033905933, -74.10568445116508 4.721873348061513, -74.10420772338625 4.722584201678661, -74.10275629999998 4.7227995, -74.10130487661371 4.722584201678661, -74.09995094883489 4.721945648061514, -74.09403374773316 4.716245366420819, -74.09338219367824 4.71525808368413, -74.09288787359796 4.71387655161008, -74.09288787359796 4.711925648389919, -74.0936469519385 4.710096948834901, -74.09548963357916 4.708043347733187, -74.09763068874044 4.70677727898599, -74.09460666784895 4.704312469919607, -74.09203589291714 4.702595752799392, -74.08765371631586 4.700417706321742, -74.08459603357916 4.698508252266813, -74.08273894773316 4.696641066420818, -74.08206922275886 4.695561432010757, -74.08118604773318 4.694727366420818, -74.0717936025263 4.682825210334004, -74.06562484883489 4.678834648061513, -74.06390001213198 4.677314420684328, -74.0535710885149 4.739037649974117, -74.05520778283815 4.737937702337444, -74.05712119999998 4.7375571, -74.06045152338628 4.738003698321339, -74.06217206642083 4.738923347733187, -74.06340970632175 4.74043141631587, -74.06393542640203 4.74187004838992, -74.06400742363337 4.743335585701648, -74.063537026402 4.74698295161008, -74.06279044806149 4.748785351165098, -74.06139073691359 4.75018144712255, -74.0609743487264 4.751890490745711, -74.06128649999999 4.753612599999999, -74.06107120167866 4.755064023386272, -74.06039964806149 4.756487551165098, -74.0594142664208 4.757574752266813, -74.05806621716184 4.758372197662556, -74.05615280000001 4.7587528, -74.05377854838993 4.758482026402016, -74.0507277649826 4.757844764394359, -74.05055722640202 4.75945045161008, -74.04983964400328 4.762451751932777, -74.04873032640204 4.76925805161008, -74.04829449766255 4.770818617161826, -74.04766074258318 4.772140089033794, -74.04726809766255 4.773711517161825, -74.04651375226682 4.774970066420818, -74.04542655116509 4.775955448061513, -74.04410012338627 4.776582801678661, -74.04215861429836 4.776774023633361, -74.04029171631588 4.776207706321742, -74.03878364773318 4.774970066420818, -74.03800540233745 4.773666917161825, -74.03729177636662 4.771281485701648, -74.03727967636664 4.770004014298352, -74.03747549832134 4.769002476613728, -74.03843161386389 4.767199327773277, -74.04047532279198 4.75512284897233, -74.0369408023945 4.754256982815782, -74.03025007661371 4.753148101678661, -74.02876484883491 4.752415548061514, -74.02767764773319 4.751430166420819, -74.02692330233745 4.750171617161826, -74.02654087636664 4.748620285701648, -74.02683367636664 4.736912214298353, -74.02739999367826 4.73504531631587, -74.02863763357918 4.733537247733187, -74.03035817661373 4.732617598321339, -74.03229968570164 4.732426376366639, -74.03372301716183 4.732782902337444, -74.03534513390593 4.733866766094067, -74.03621920632175 4.73504531631587, -74.03676491551958 4.736773285680133, -74.04355019487681 4.738452884397855, -74.04767016881966 4.714185707761746, -74.04885077359798 4.706409648389919, -74.05027314410287 4.698677293675041, -74.05045487359796 4.696561148389919, -74.05077748485968 4.695365046361829, -74.05289107166563 4.682999393176747, -74.05422957359798 4.67404324838992, -74.05473458359565 4.671889824337649, -74.05543207359798 4.667273848389919, -74.05644319847762 4.664371152795165))'
polygon_3 = shapely.wkt.loads(poly_3_wkt)
poly_4_wkt = 'Polygon ((22.11315279161000547 -25.09231820047121886, 21.62718174901616663 -26.2204652636354929, 22.01769419395764515 -27.5308514677724574, 23.33675845242663982 -28.13831527101475416, 24.77731547154409597 -27.47010508744822488, 24.86409601486442256 -26.98413404485438605, 23.92686614700487624 -26.97545599052235232, 24.55168605891124045 -26.38534829594411946, 25.86207226304820495 -26.14236277464719649, 26.1918383276654545 -26.70643630622933529, 25.92281864337243391 -27.30522205513960188, 26.69516547892335723 -26.88867544720202218, 26.75591185924758975 -26.19443110063939528, 25.93149669770446764 -25.73449422104165407, 25.51495008976689149 -25.98615779667060366, 25.14179375348947687 -25.69978200371352273, 24.68185687389173566 -25.25720123277984541, 23.85744171234861355 -26.09029444865500125, 23.71859284303608462 -26.81925101254575949, 22.81607519250466964 -26.2204652636354929, 23.26733401777037713 -25.343981776100172, 23.17187542011801682 -24.90140100516649824, 22.77268492084450457 -24.55427883188518123, 22.11315279161000547 -25.09231820047121886),(22.46027496489132247 -25.79524060136588304, 22.01769419395764515 -26.19443110063939528, 22.2172894435943995 -26.38534829594411946, 22.45159691055928874 -26.48948494792850994, 22.55573356254368278 -26.53287521958867501, 22.49498718221945381 -26.75850463222153053, 22.92021184448906368 -26.68908019756526784, 22.33010414991082726 -26.32460191561988694, 22.5817677255397804 -26.02087001399873856, 22.93756795315312758 -25.3786939934283069, 22.81607519250466964 -25.343981776100172, 22.46027496489132247 -25.79524060136588304),(23.10245098546175413 -27.53952952210448757, 22.54705550821164906 -27.47010508744822488, 22.81607519250466964 -27.05355847951064874, 23.64049035404779175 -27.17505124015910667, 23.692558680039987 -27.59159784809668636, 23.18055347445005054 -27.85193947805767323, 23.10245098546175413 -27.53952952210448757),(24.24795415729009207 -26.20310915497142901, 24.36076886360651983 -25.94276752501044214, 24.70789103688783328 -25.95144557934247587, 24.81202768887222732 -25.95144557934247587, 24.77731547154409597 -25.78656254703384931, 25.0810473731652479 -25.91673336201434097, 25.07236931883321418 -26.10765055731906514, 24.65582271089563449 -26.15104082897923021, 24.34341275494245238 -26.38534829594411946, 24.24795415729009207 -26.20310915497142901))'
polygon_4 = shapely.wkt.loads(poly_4_wkt)

to_triangles(polygon_2)
```

Old Answer

**
I know this is an old post but someone still might find this helpful. Other than cutting the result with the original you can convert the resulting triangles into centroids, select the centroids inside the original polygon with a inner join query (geopandas.sjoin()). Select the triangles where the intersecting original id is equal to the original polygon id (necessary step for multi-polygons). Then select the new triangles where the new triangle ids are within the intersecting triangulated centroid ids.

The code below also handles multi-polygons:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import triangulate

# Creating the polygon
res_intersection = [Polygon([(3.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.75), (2.5, 0.75), (2.5, 0.6), (2.25, 0.6), (2.25, 0.2), (3.0, 0.2), (3.0, 0.0)])]
res_intersection_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
res_intersection_gdf.geometry = res_intersection
# Create ID to identify overlapping polygons
res_intersection_gdf['TRI_ID'] = res_intersection_gdf.index
# List to keep triangulated geometries
tri_geom = []
# List to keep the original IDs
tri_id = []
# Triangulate single or multi-polygons
for i, rows in res_intersection_gdf.iterrows():
    tri_ = triangulate(res_intersection_gdf.geometry.values[i])
    tri_geom.append(tri_)
    for id_length in range(0, len(tri_)):
        tri_id.append(res_intersection_gdf.TRI_ID.values[i])
# Check if it is a single or multi-polygon
len_list = len(tri_geom)
tri_geom = np.array(tri_geom).flatten().tolist()
# unlist geometries for multi-polygons
if len_list > 1:
    tri_geom = [item for sublist in tri_geom for item in sublist]
# Create triangulated polygons
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(tri_geom)
polygon = polygon.set_geometry(tri_geom)
del polygon[0]
# Assign original IDs to each triangle
polygon['TRI_ID'] = tri_id
# Create new ID for each triangle
polygon['LINK_ID'] = polygon.index
# Create centroids from all triangulated polygons
polygon['centroid'] = polygon.centroid
polygon_centroid = polygon.set_geometry('centroid')
del polygon_centroid['geometry']
del polygon['centroid']
# Find triangle centroids inside original polygon
polygon_join = gpd.sjoin(polygon_centroid[['centroid', 'TRI_ID', 'LINK_ID']], res_intersection_gdf[['geometry', 'TRI_ID']], how='inner', op='within')
# Remove overlapping from other polygons (Necessary for multi-polygons overlapping or close to each other)
polygon_join = polygon_join[polygon_join['TRI_ID_left']==polygon_join['TRI_ID_right']]
# Remove overload triangles from same polygons
polygon = polygon[polygon['LINK_ID'].isin(polygon_join['LINK_ID'])]
```

[image: Result of script]

For shapefiles, just load the polygons with geopandas replacing the "creating polygons" section.

Note: I had one very very complicated polygon where the results where irregular but worked for most complex polygons, even polygons with holes.

Comment: This is really nice! Is there anything equivalent to decompose the polygon into rectangles instead. Alternatively a method to group two consecutive triangles in what you did into quadrilateral polygons?

Comment: I did a quick search and tried a few things but came up short. I  think it might be best to post our question for more qualified users to help. That said, you can look at rasterizing or creating a vector grid which you clip using your polygon . I'm not convinced that simply dissolving consecutive triangles will give you desirable results and will have to cater for odd number triangles but see if this will help: `polygon['dis']  = polygon['TRI_ID'].astype(str) +'-'+ (np.divmod(np.arange(len(polygon)),2)[0]+1).astype(str)
gdf_rect = polygon.dissolve(by='dis')
gdf_rect.plot()`

Comment: I'll admit that I don't fully understand your answer since I have never used geopandas, but it sounds like it might not account for triangles being partially inside the original polygon? (Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019170/how-do-you-triangulate-a-polygon-in-shapely?noredirect=1#comment125015008_65019170 )

Comment: You were right. There are some triangles that is left out using the old answer. I have updated my answer and tested it on a few polygons. Even polygons with holes. Still want to see if there is a better/faster way using the libraries meshPy or Triangle

Answer (score 1):

There is simple way to do it with shapely: loop on the `triangulate()` results and use binary predicate `within` to check if the triangle is inside.

```
def triangulate_within(polygon):
    return [triangle for triangle in triangulate(polygon) if triangle.within(polygon)]
```

Comment: That's not enough, triangles can be partially inside. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019170/how-do-you-triangulate-a-polygon-in-shapely?noredirect=1#comment125015008_65019170